# How to make a saturation value slider with OpenCV in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv, hsv

I want to make a slider that can change the saturation of the image in an image view.

I'm currently using OpenCV. I've found some code on the web and tried it. It's working but it works in a little bit strange way..There is a white cup on the image but its color goes all the way rainbow regardless of the value(unless it's totally grayscale).

```
- (IBAction)stSlider:(id)sender {

float value = stSlider.value;

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sushi.jpg"];
cv::Mat mat = [self cvMatFromUIImage:image];

cv::cvtColor(mat, mat, CV_RGB2HSV);



for (int i=0; i<mat.rows;i++)
{ for (int j=0; j<mat.cols;j++)
{
    int idx = 1;
    mat.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[idx] = value;

}
}

cv::cvtColor(mat, mat, CV_HSV2RGB);
imageView.image = [self UIImageFromCVMat:mat];

}
```

This is the code I used.
Please tell me which part I have to change to make it work right.

Comment: i doubt, that you want to set each s-value in the image to the same value. += or *= maybe

Comment: thanks..!! i must have misunderstood the concept of saturation